# WebSocket Frame length changes when masked

Tags: c++, node.js, websocket

I am writing a simple program that communicates through the websocket protocol. It needs to be able to mask and unmask messages. When I receive a message (after handshaking and stuff) I simply put it in a struct:

```
struct WSFrame
{
    unsigned char frame_fin : 1;
    unsigned char frame_rsv1 : 1;
    unsigned char frame_rsv2 : 1;
    unsigned char frame_rsv3 : 1;
    unsigned char frame_opcode : 4;
    unsigned char frame_masked : 1;
    unsigned char frame_payload_length : 7;
}
```

The variables fin, rsv123, opcode and masked are automatically correct.
Now I cast the length to an int (and of course when the length is longer I cast to short or long according to RFC):

```
int payloadLength = this->frame_payload_length << 1;
```

This works fine except for when the message is masked. Sometimes the variable "masked" still is 0 and the length always fails to be within 0-127 (get's 3000+ somewhere). Do I need to get the length differently for masked messages? For reference, the server is written with NodeJS and the client is C++. This problem occurs on the client, which I am writing myself.

Comment: Any reason why you're not using an existing C/C++ websockets library (e.g. [libwebsockets](https://libwebsockets.org/)) instead?

Comment: My project does not require tens of thousands of files just to send a single websocket message.